# Google Sheets Email - Vlookup showing REF value in PDF

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, vlookup, gs-vlookup

Hoping you could help me with this, I have created a system that automatically sends the current sheet as an attachment in an email with body and subject text.
I have one problem that I cant seem to solve;  the Vlookup used in the sheet generates either a blank column or a REF! on the emailed PDF. And any info directing to another value from a different sheet (eg ='Sheet2'!D2)

Here is the code used on the sheet triggering the PDF attachment :

```
    function mailCCB() {
var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();                            //get active spreadsheet
var message = "Good Day." + "\n\n" + "Please find attached certificate";         //email body
var certNo = originalSpreadsheet.getRange("C7").getValue();                      //certificate number  
var cust = originalSpreadsheet.getRange("E10").getValues();                      //customer name
var subject = "Certificate " + certNo + " | " + cust;                 //email subject
var emailTo = originalSpreadsheet.getRange("E13").getValue();                    //email address
var sheets = originalSpreadsheet.getSheets();                                    //get all sheets
var sheetName = originalSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName();                  //get current sheet name
var sourceSheet = originalSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);                 //source sheet
// Get folder containing spreadsheet to save pdf in.
  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(originalSpreadsheet.getId()).getParents();
  if (parents.hasNext()) {
    var folder =  parents.next();
  }
  else {
    folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  }
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Working on it.. 50%", "Busy",12);
  // Copy whole spreadsheet.
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(originalSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))

  // Delete redundant sheets.
  var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){

      destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }
  var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
  var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Working on it.. 60%", "Busy",12);
    var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
  destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);
  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(subject);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
//*****************************

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast("Working on it.. 75%", "Busy",12);
// Create a new Spreadsheet and copy the current sheet into it.
var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Spreadsheet to export");
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var projectname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
sheet = originalSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);


var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(originalSpreadsheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
var attach = {fileName:'Klerkscale Certificate',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};
MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {attachments:[theBlob]});

DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);  

originalSpreadsheet.toast("Certificate will be sent shortly to " + emailTo,"Success",20);
}
```

This is the cropped received email result :

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this, it's working for me, could give an example of the vlookup functions you're using and the data that it's targeting (values and type of data)?

Comment: @AndresDuarte Using either one still produces the same result, but here is both :

1.   =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B$70,Data!$A$2:$BL$249,3,false),"")

2.  =VLOOKUP($J$56,Customers!$A$2:$H$125,8,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I saw your problem, you're deleting all the sheets which are being referenced by the active sheet in `destSpreadsheet` thus they will not be available and the results will be `#REF!` for each cell referencing those deleted sheets. To solve that problem you could use the [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) method, which retrieves the current displayed value of the cell instead of `getValues()` which retrieves the function(`VLOOKUP` in this case) set in the cell. Change this line:

```
  var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
```

For this:

```
  var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getDisplayValues();
```

Also, don't delete the other sheets which are being referenced until you have copyied the values to `destRange` in this line:

```
  destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);
```

Comment: Thank you, the issue was the data being deleted first.